# How can I add an email adapter to my amazon EC2 instance to enable password resets for my app

Tags: amazon-ec2, parse-server, mailgun, parse-cloud-code, aws-code-deploy

The steps that I have already done are as follows:

1)I've set up my EC2 instance already.
2) I've linked it up to amazon CodeDeploy 
3) I've created an s3 bucket that will hold my cloud code when I push it to my instance.
4) I've created a folder that will contain my cloud code.
5) I've initialised npm within it and created an index.js file (it is a sublime text file actually - not sure if this is correct or not?)
6)  I've set things up from the command line that index.js is the main entry point.
7) I have put the following email adapter code within it:

```
var server = ParseServer({

  // Enable email verification
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  // The public URL of your app.
  // This will appear in the link that is used to verify email addresses and reset passwords.
  // Set the mount path as it is in serverURL
  publicServerURL: 'etc',
  // Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
  appName: 'etc',
  // The email adapter
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      // The address that your emails come from
      fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
      // Your domain from mailgun.com
      domain: 'example.com',
      // Your API key from mailgun.com
      apiKey: 'key-mykey',
    }
  }
});
```

8) I've set up an account with mailgun  its asking me for a domain to send the emails from? I'm not sure what this is?

My main question is regarding the code i posted above. Is this enough to put into index.js to create an email adapter? And is uploading a sublime text file ok? How can the cloud know what "ParseServer" class is without importing libraries? - Do i have to add anymore code to index.js?

Additionally what else do I need in the cloud code package besides the index.js file? This has been such an obscure topic and there seems to be no clear guides online as to how to upload functional cloud code to amazon EC2 instances.

Any help appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your steps are correct but you must also modify the **form** and the **domain**. Your domain (to your question) must be taken from your mailgun account. You must add some steps in order to setup your domain with your DNS provider (e.g. goDaddy etc.) If you don't want to use you can try to use the default sandbox domain that has been provided to you by mail-gun but it's better to use your own domain. In the **from** field you need to put some email address so users that will receive the email will see from which email this message sent to them. usually what I love to put is **donotreplay@** ( is your domain of course)

In my project, this is how I configure it (and it works):

```
 "verifyUserEmails": true,
"emailAdapter": {
    "module": "parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter",
    "options": {
        "fromAddress": "donotreply@*******.com",
        "domain": "mail.*******.com",
        "apiKey": "<API_KEY_TAKEN_FROM_MAILGUN>"
    }
},
```

Your list of domain in mail-gun can be found in here: https://app.mailgun.com/app/domains  (login is required of course)

in here: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#verifying-your-domain you can read how to **verify your domain**

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, so do I need to put anything else in index.js and the rest of the package that I upload to codedeploy?

Comment: No, it should work as it is. You just need to make sure that you specified the right values and that's it. I also recommend you to test it locally before deploying it.

Comment: Thank you, and what do I put for the "public server url"? Is that just my amazon ec2 server DNS?

Comment: You don’t must to put something there but usually this is the same value as your serverURL